# Decompile & recompile single file from jar

Tags: java, decompiling

***This problem has been solved witht he help of the comments:***

It was necessary to recompile the java with the correct target version. In my case `javac -source 1.3 -target 1.3` instead of simply `javac` did the trick.

**Problem Description:**

I have a compiled .jar java program in which a single url string needs to be modified. Using JD I was able to decompile the code and make the changes.

As I would like to avoid having to recompile the entire project I thought I could simply recompile the single .java file I modified into a .class and replace the original with it.

However, after repackaging the jar, the program does start but the functionality making use of the code I modified behaves erratically.

In the log I find:

```
E EventDispatchThreadExceptionHandler:Unhandled exception occurred during event dispatching.::
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.myCompany.mySoftware.resources.ModuleResources, locale en_US
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:842)
```

ModuleResources.java is the file I modified...

**Analysis of the problem:**

1. Repackageing is not at fault: if I extract and repackage the original jar, everything works.
2. My modification does equally not seem to be the problem: when I recompile the JD-decompiled java file and use the resulting class file for repackaging, I get the same failure.

I decompiled the repackaged jar file and compared it with the decompilation of the original jar file: In the file I modified (at least) the code seems to be identical BUT JD shows different line numbers. Could that hint at the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: "the program does not run" is pretty vague - please give more information.

Comment: What version of Java were the classes in the JAR compiled against? What version of Java are you using to recompile the class? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Generally, it should work this way. Like John said, we need more information on the problem - do you see exceptions?

Comment: Ok, I see the problem description was far too vague. Please see the modified question. I am not sure which version of java the classes were compiled against. How can I find out?

Comment: From what I see the java version installed on the device in question is cvm 1.3. I recompiled the .java file with the current JDK (Java SE 7). Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Perception Many thanks. You put me on the right path! After compiling with javac -source 1.3 -target 1.3 everything works now.

Comment: @Perception Would you write an answer for the OP to accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the old question.

Nowadays, I found the good method to decompile and repack the jar file.

Here is the good document.

https://www.talksinfo.com/how-to-edit-class-file-from-a-jar/

I recommend the third method in the document.!!!

Answer (score 0):

> when I recompile the JD-decompiled java file and use the resulting class file for repackaging, I get the same failure

This seems to point the finger at JD. When you recompile the JD-decompiled java file, can you compare the result with the original `.class` file (for example, by disassembling both and comparing the result)? If they differ in substance, that'll lend credence to the theory that JD is at fault; if they don't, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: As I said in the question, the disassembled code of both is identical in substance, except for the line numbers JD shows.

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke: Your question does not even mention the word "disassemble". You are talking about decompilation, and I am talking about disassembly. The latter is far more precise as far as detecting differences in bytecodes is concerned.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I read "disassembling" but understood "decompiling". My problem is resolved, but for future reference, how does one "disassemble" byte code?

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke: `javap -c`

Comment: I am using this one here http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ - It appears to decompile correctly. The issue is compiling it again