# is there a way to make changes in jar which doesnot have source code in it and rebuild it as a jar in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Is there a way to make changes in jar which doesnot have source code in it and rebuild it with this change as a jar in eclipse.

Comment: Ooh, this will open the door to crazy, unrepairable bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using Java **decompilers**; in order to turn the .class files within the JAR archive back into .java source code. The process and some tools for that are outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144539/change-jar-file-without-the-source).

But: understand that *decompiling" can be a tough business! Plus: there is always the question if the **licence** terms of the library you are using allows you to do that. Being able to do something isn't the same as being allowed to do that!

Finally: keep in mind that a JAR is just a deployment artifact. A lot of libraries are open source, and you can most often download that source and build the corresponding JARs completely on your own.